# DeviceToDevice bandwidth formula in CUDA sample code bandwitdhTest

Tags: cuda

The formula in the sample code provided with the SDK is the following (for DtoD transfer):

`bandwidthInMBs = 2.0f * ((float)(1<<10) * memSize * (float)MEMCOPY_ITERATIONS) / (elapsedTimeInMs * (float)(1 << 20));`

The **2.0f** multiplier in the beginning does not exist for the DtoH and HtoD cases. Why? Is this because for the DtoD case, two copying operations are performed, so twice the **memSize** is actually transferred?

Also, how accurate is this formula on a physically unified system such as the Jetson TK1? Is the **2.0f** multiplier necessary?

For example, on the Jetson TK1 I'm getting the following numbers:

DtoH = 6.1  GB/s

HtoD = 6.1  GB/s

DtoD = 12.2 GB/s (just because of the multiplier!)

Comment: @harrism any insights are appreciated.

Comment: The DtoD test reads 6.1 GB/sec from the device memory, and writes 6.1 GB/sec to the device memory, so total device memory bandwidth is 12.2 Gb/sec. For a system where the host and device memory is the same physical memory, the same 2x multiplier should probably be applied to the HtoD and DtoH tests. I guess the app simply does not make any special provisions for this scenario. In the standard case of a system with a discrete GPU, HtoD and DtoH case each require x GB/sec of host memory and x GB/sec of device memory bandwidth, while the DtoD case requires 2x GB/sec of device memory bandwidth.

Comment: @njuffa, I think it all comes down to how cudaMemcpy() is actually implemented for the different copy directions. So, on discrete GPUs, I guess there is no multiplier for DtoH and HtoD because there is a single copy using the device DMA copy engine over PCIe. I also know that on discrete GPUs DtoD copy is done using a Memcpy kernel that is launched by the driver on the SMs (which I guess reads first, then writes and as you said the reason for the 2x). So the question is whether the Jetson TK1 driver uses the same implementations of cudaMemcpy for the different directions or not.

Comment: Implementation has nothing to do with bandwidth to/from GPU-attached memory (which is what the app tries to measure). The app obviously predates GPU platforms with unified physical memory and apparently has not been adapted to a situation where host and device memory are the same physical memory. Your results provide useful information: TK1 can read 6.1 GB/sec from attached memory, simultaneously write 6.1 GB/sec to attached memory, for total bandwidth of 12.1 GB/sec. This is consistent with DDR3 memory on a 64-bit interface (consumer PCs with two-channel DDR3 provide about 25 GB/sec)

Comment: @njuffa, if implementation has nothing to do with it, then a regular memcpy() should be equivalent to cudaMemcpy(), which is not the case. I added a HostToHost case to the app where I copy a  regular malloc'd region to another on the host, and measured bandwidth with the same above formula, and the result is **4.2 GB/s**. (I also get the same results if I use HostToHost cudaMemcpy). Shouldn't we have 12.2 GB/s in this case as well since we're still performing the copies using the 64 bit wide memory interface?

Comment: My comment about implementation was with regard to the discrepancy between 6.1 GB/sec reported for HtoD and DtoH 6.1 vs 12.2 GB/sec reported  for DtoD that you inquired about in your original question. I pointed out that those numbers are in fact consistent based on how the test app reports, and are plausible. This is not a discussion forum, and you seem to be looking at some different issue now, so please ask a new question.

Comment: I have added an answer summarizing the comments in an attempt to get this question off the unanswered list for the CUDA tag

Answer (score 1):

*[ Summarizing comments into a answer with the hope of getting the question off the unanswered list for the CUDA tag where it has been languishing for more than four years ]*

> The 2.0f multiplier in the beginning does not exist for the DtoH and
>   HtoD cases. Why?

Because (in a conventional system) a device-to-host or host-to-device operation involves only either read or write operations in device memory. A device-to-device operation involves both a read from, and a write to device memory, thus twice as many device memory transactions are involved per byte of transfer and double the memory bandwidth is being consumed.

> Is this because for the DtoD case, two copying operations are
>   performed, so twice the memSize is actually transferred?

More or less, yes.

> Also, how accurate is this formula on a physically unified system such as the Jetson TK1?

Nothing changes. A device-to-device transfer still involves two memory transactions per byte transfers, thus twice the bandwidth is consumed.

> Is the 2.0f multiplier necessary?

Yes, and you could argue that the two times multiplier is also required for host-to-device and device-to host-transfers on shared memory systems, because they are, in essence, identical operations to the device-to-device transfers and consume twice the memory bandwidth per byte of memory transfer.